# Laravel: redirect to another controller which requires POST variables

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have ReportController
Index which is routed as POST only

```
public function index() // must have start, end, client
{
    $start  = Input::get('start'); // <<< This are POST variables
    $end    = Input::get('end');   // <<< This are POST variables
    $client = Input::get('client'); This are POST variables

    db request... output view..

}
```

when I click "delete row", it post info to

```
public function deleteRow()
{
    db request -> delete();
    //How do I go back to index controller and pass same $_POST['start'],$_POST['end'],$_POST['client']
}
```

How do I go back to index controller and pass same $_POST['start'],$_POST['end'],$_POST['client']?

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/requests#old-input

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use `Redirect::to('url')->withInput()`

Then you can use `Input::get('key')`

If that doesn't work, try `Input::old('key')` -> Less pretty

Comment: withInput() +  Input::old worked 

Only bug is when I press refresh page, it looses data.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, since withInput() supposedly only 'flash' your data to next request, it only persist for one good next request.

Comment: Also consider accepting this answer so it helps someone else with similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Your post variables are no longer available once you make another request to the `deleteRow` method from the view, so you have to pass those variables to the `deleteRow` method. You build a `view/ui` from your `index` method like

```
public function index() // must have start, end, client
{
    $start  = Input::get('start');
    $end    = Input::get('end');
    $client = Input::get('client');

    db request... output view.. // <-- Outputs view with "delete row" link
}
```

Hope, you pass those `post` variables in this view, if not then pass those variables to this view and build the `delete row` link with these `variables`, something like

```
"ReportController/deleteRow/$start/$end/$client" // just an idea
```

Which means, your `deleteRow` method now should look like (also make changes in the routing of this)

```
public function deleteRow($start, $end, $client)
{
    // db request -> delete();
    return Redirect::to('index')
    ->with('postVars', array('start' => $start, '$end' => $end, 'client', $client));
}
```

So, it's clear that you have to pass those variables to the `deleteRow` method and that's why `deleteRow` methods `route` should be reconstructed according to the `params`. So, finally, your `index` method should look like

```
public function index() // must have start, end, client
{
    $postVars = session::has('postVars') ? session::get('postVars') : Input:all();
    $start = $postVars['start'];
    $end = $postVars['end'];
    $client = $postVars['client'];

    db request... output view..

}
```